# Where is .aws directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I try to learn AWS and follow some manual from Udemy.
I try to follow the lesson where I need to manage the `c:/Users/home/.aws` directory. This folder contains users credentials, but I haven't this directory on my windows machine.

My steps:

- I created windows server
- Created user
- The user is logined to the AWS-server
- I connected to the windows-machine with Administrator credentials
- Installed `awscli`

In the tutorial lector get to the `c:/users/home/.aws` directory, but I haven't such a folder on my machine. What is this folder and which actions do I need to execute?

-

Comment: `aws configure` creates the driectory.

Comment: @jordanm a lot of thanks! This is the answer